# Collapse text by group in data frame

Tags: r

How do I aggregate data frame by group in column `group` and collapse text in column `text`?

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="
group text
a a1
a a2
a a3
b b1
b b2
c c1
c c2
c c3
")
```

Required output (data frame):

```
group text
a     a1a2a3
b     b1b2
c     c1c2c3
```

Now I have:

```
sapply(unique(df$group), function(x) {
  paste0(df[df$group==x,"text"], collapse='')
})
```

This works to some extent as it returns text properly collapsed by group, but as a vector:

```
[1] "a1a2a3" "b1b2"   "c1c2c3"
```

I need a data frame with `group` column as a result.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Simply use `aggregate` :

```
aggregate(df$text, list(df$group), paste, collapse="")
##   Group.1      x
## 1       a a1a2a3
## 2       b   b1b2
## 3       c c1c2c3
```

Or with `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(group), summarize, text=paste(text, collapse=""))
##   group   text
## 1     a a1a2a3
## 2     b   b1b2
## 3     c c1c2c3
```

`ddply` is faster than `aggregate` if you have a large dataset.

**EDIT** :
With the suggestion from @SeDur :

```
aggregate(text ~ group, data = df, FUN = paste, collapse = "")
##   group   text
## 1     a a1a2a3
## 2     b   b1b2
## 3     c c1c2c3
```

For the same result with earlier method you have to do :

```
aggregate(x=list(text=df$text), by=list(group=df$group), paste, collapse="")
```

**EDIT2** : With `data.table` :

```
library("data.table")
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, list(text = paste(text, collapse="")), by = group]
##    group   text
## 1:     a a1a2a3
## 2:     b   b1b2
## 3:     c c1c2c3
```

Comment: using the formula form of `aggregate`gives prettier name : aggregate( text ~ group, data = df, FUN = paste, collapse = "")

Comment: @rawr that's in the first edit

Comment: The non-formula `aggregate` doesn't need to be as torturous either - `aggregate(df["text"], df["group"], paste, collapse="")` will do it just fine.

Answer (score 29):

You can use dplyr package for this

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(text=paste(text,collapse=''))
```

Comment: when you collapse all rows, how can you keep all variable values and not just one assigned one?