# Import data in R from multiple files with name pattern

Tags: r

I have a list of files in CSV format, for example:

> 20150507.csv

```
a,10 
b,20 
c,30
```

> 20150506.csv

```
a,100 
b,20 
c,1
```

and so on. I have a text file containing variable names:

> list.txt

```
a 
b 
c 
d
```

I need to import the data in such a way that I have values for the variables in the `list.txt` file:

```
a: 10, 100,... 
b: 20, 20, ... 
c: 30, 1, ...
```

Values of elements (from `list.txt`) are searched from all CSV files that match the date name pattern, and after collecting all the values, I need to compute the mean and SD of each variable, and mark observations that are more than 2 SD away from the mean as outliers.

Currently I am using `bash` commands to create statistics for each element of `list.txt` and then load data in R.

```
for i in `cat list.txt |cut -d, -f1`; do echo "$i";grep "^$i" 2015* | cut -d: -f2 > /tmp/$i.stat;done
```

and then use a `for` loop in R to find outliers:

```
files=list.files(path="/tmp/",pattern=".stat")

for( i in 1:length( files)){
    myfunction(paste("/tmp/",files[[i]],sep='')
}

myfunction(filename)
    {df <- read.csv(filename, header=F); 
    names(df)=c("symbol","num");

    x=df[abs(df$num-mean(df$num))>2*sd(df[,2]),];outl=(nrow(x)/nrow(df))*100;if(outl>1){cat(filename,"\n");

    cat("outliers=",outl);cat("\n\n")
```

However I would like to do the whole process in R only rather than creating multiple files through `bash` and then read them using a `for` loop.

I read [this grep manual for R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) , however searching multiple file options does not show up.

### Edit:

Instead of using `for`,  I have now used:

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(path="/tmp/",pattern = "*.stat"), read.csv,header=FALSE))
```

which looks like a better way.

However `df2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(path="/orignal/dir/",pattern = "2015*.abc.csv"), read.csv,header=FALSE))` doesnt make R understand that I'm searching for all files with names starting with 2015* and ending with abc.csv

Comment: As you have managed to import all CSVs into 1 dataframe, your problem sounds like a duplicate of this post: [Collapse text by group in data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756372/collapse-text-by-group-in-data-frame)

Comment: @zx8754 , but the problem of creating multiple stat files still remains. I have added more to the question. @ fg nu added more details, hope it makes it more clear. And i couldnt find what's wrong with the function, could you please hint

Comment: There is no need for a hint -- that is not how you define a function in R.

Comment: df2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(path="/orignal/dir/",pattern = "2015*.abc.csv"), read.csv,header=FALSE)) doesnt make it understand like bash , it searches for all files instead.
@fgnu yes syntactically it is wrong I'll correct it

Comment: Is the number and order of columns variable or fixed?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik number of columns in all date.abc.csv are same (its 2), number of rows may vary. Current problem is stuck with me unable to specify particular files to list.files

Comment: I think it would be best if you break your question into two or three separate specific questions. Also, please provide a reproducible example (it's easy to generate the data/files using built in functions).