# in R choosing specific values from two rows sharing unique ids but keeping only one row

Tags: r

In R: For a given data frame `dummy` that looks like:

```
dummy <- data.frame(a = c("b01", "b01", "b02"), 
                    id = c(456, 456, 233),
                    id2 = c(888, 888, 889), 
                    t = c("neg", "no", "pos"),
                    j = c("no", "no", "no"), 
                    y = c("pos", "no", "neg"),  
                    q = c("pos", "no", "no"),  
                    w = c("asd", "asd", "sdf"))

#     a  id id2   t   j   y   q   w
# 1 b01 456 888 neg  no  no pos asd   
# 2 b01 456 888  no  no pos  no asd
# 3 b02 233 889 pos  no neg  no sdf
```

I want to merge the rows by columns `a`, `id`, and `id2` but I only want to keep the corresponding `neg` or `pos`, when they appear in either of the rows, and `no` if both are `no`.

I've tried:

```
library(dplyr)
z <- dummy %>%  
     group_by(a, id, id2) %>%  
     summarise(  
          t = paste(t, collapse = "-"),  
          j = paste(j, collapse = "-"),  
          y = paste(y, collapse = "-"),  
          q = paste(q, collapse = "-")
```

And it will do it (after removing unwanted text with `gsub`) but then column w is dropped..

The desired data frame would look like this:

```
#     a  id id2   t   j   y   q   w
# 1 b01 456 888 neg  no pos pos asd  
# 3 b02 233 889 pos  no neg  no sdf
```

Any help would be appreciated.
I've also looked at:
([Collapse text by group in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756372/collapse-text-by-group-in-data-frame)) and ([dplyr summarise: Equivalent of ".drop=FALSE" to keep groups with zero length in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523131/dplyr-summarise-equivalent-of-drop-false-to-keep-groups-with-zero-length-in))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modification of your original approach using `summarise()` instead of `mutate()` so you can do it all in one step.

```
z <- dummy %>%  
     group_by(a, id, id2) %>%  
     summarise(t = ifelse(length(unique(t))==1, as.character(unique(t)), as.character(t[which(t!="no")])),
               j = ifelse(length(unique(j))==1, as.character(unique(j)), as.character(j[which(j!="no")])),
               y = ifelse(length(unique(y))==1, as.character(unique(y)), as.character(y[which(y!="no")])),
               q = ifelse(length(unique(q))==1, as.character(unique(q)), as.character(q[which(q!="no")])),
               w = unique(w))
```

Result:

```
> z
Source: local data frame [2 x 8]
Groups: a, id [?]

       a    id   id2     t     j     y     q      w
  (fctr) (dbl) (dbl) (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr) (fctr)
1    b01   456   888   neg   neg   pos   pos    asd
2    b02   233   889   pos    no   neg    no    sdf
```

If the variables in your data frame are strings instead of factors, you can get rid of all the `as.character()` bits in that code.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it but the `j` variable should throw a `no` instead of a `neg` for `a==b01`. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Your sample answer shows a "no" there, but if you apply your rules to the version of `dummy` your code makes, you should get a "neg" there, because `j=="neg"` for one of the rows where `a==b01 & id==456 & id2==888`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
Instead of `summarise()`, I used `mutate()` and all worked fine.
Thanks everyone!