# Color highlighting text in R for a pre-defined list of words

Tags: r, text, highlight, cpu-word

Suppose I have a collection of documents such as:

```
text = c("is it possible to highlight text for some words" , 
      "suppose i want words like words to be red and words like text to be blue")
```

I am wondering whether it is possible to highlight documents (particularly for a large corpus) with colors for a pre-defined list of words using R. Each word in the list will get a specific color. For example, highlighting "words" to be red and "text" to be blue as shown below.

[image]

Comment: This would be easy if you were going to save the text to a HTML file or something. Where are you hoping to save the results, and where should the colours be viewable?

Comment: Not within R itself, but the R2wd and officer packages are good for formatting things to a word document, then the knittr and markdown ones are good for making a html.

Comment: Marius - I am using R shinyapp and the results will be demonstrated in R shinyapp using DataTables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a somewhat hackish solution to this question and not very scalable for large corpus. I will be curious to see if there is a much more parsimonious, elegant, and scalable way to do this.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(crayon)

# define text
text <- c("is it possible to highlight text for some words" , 
         "suppose i want words like words to be red and words like text to be blue")

# individuate words
unique_words <- function(x) {
  purrr::map(.x = x,
             .f = ~ unique(base::strsplit(x = ., split = " ")[[1]],
                           collapse = " "))
}

# creating a dataframe with crayonized text
df <- 
  tibble::enframe(unique_words(x = text)) %>%
  tidyr::unnest() %>%
# here you can specify the color/word combinations you need 
  dplyr::mutate(.data = .,
                value2 = dplyr::case_when(value == "text" ~ crayon::blue(value),
                                          value == "words" ~ crayon::red(value),
                TRUE ~ value)) %>%
  dplyr::select(., -value) 

# printing the text
print(cat(df$value2))
```

[image]

P.S. Unfortunately, `reprex` doesn't work with colored text, so can't produce the complete reprex.

Comment: Thanks Indrajeet. yes, it does not produce the complete one, but good work!

Answer (score 7):

Here is the full debugged app code!

First, required libraries:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(magrittr)
```

Then, the function that adds HTML tag:

```
wordHighlight <- function(SuspWord,colH = 'yellow') {
  paste0('<span style="background-color:',colH,'">',SuspWord,'</span>')
}
```

Now UI portion:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Text Highlighting"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        textInput("wordSearch", "Word Search")
      ),
    mainPanel(
        DT::dataTableOutput("table")
      )   
   )  
   )
```

Finally, on the server side:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
   sentence <- "The term 'data science' (originally used interchangeably with 'datalogy') has existed for over thirty years and was used initially as a substitute for computer science by Peter Naur in 1960."
   sentence2 = "One of the things we will want to do most often for social science analyses of text data is generate a document-term matrix."
   YourData = data.frame(N = c('001','002'), T = c(sentence,sentence2), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
   highlightData <- reactive({
     if (input$wordSearch!="")
      {
        patterns = input$wordSearch
        YourData2 = YourData
        YourData2[,2] %<>% str_replace_all(regex(patterns, ignore_case = TRUE), wordHighlight)
        return(YourData2)
      }
    return(YourData)
  })
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      data <- highlightData() 
    }, escape = FALSE)
}
```

Run the app:

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It did not work for me. Is it possible for you to give a full example (given a fake data) how your codes work in shiny app?

Comment: A good one, but not answered my question properly. For example how you can highlight word "data" with red color and word "term" with yellow color.

Comment: This is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Indrajeet's asnwer is great. This is an answer based on Indrajeet's answer, just a little bit change.

```
unique_words <- lapply(strsplit(text, " "), function(x){x[!x ==""]})

# creating a dataframe with crayonized text
df <- 
  tibble::enframe(unique_words) %>%
  tidyr::unnest() %>%

# here you can specify the color/word combinations you need 
dplyr::mutate(.data = .,
            value2 = dplyr::case_when(value == "text" ~ crayon::blue(value),
                                      value == "words" ~ crayon::red(value),
                                      TRUE ~ value)) %>%
dplyr::select(., -value)
```

[image]

Having the output in two different lines ([Collapse text by group in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756372/collapse-text-by-group-in-data-frame)):

```
df <- data.table(df)
df <- df[, list(text = paste(value2, collapse=" ")), by = name]
```

[image]

The answer looks Ok if I wanted to print it in R console. How it works if I want to have the output in R shinyapp?

Looking for other alternatives and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to Highlight list of word present in the document
This code is used inRmarkdown for creating word Document

{r highlight=TRUE}

list_of_words <- c("apple", "banana", "pear")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).